Linear Algebra: Orthogonal basis to find proj of $\mathbf{w}$ onto $\mathbf{y}$?
I'm currently studying for my final exam for linear algebra, and I'm a bit confused about how to find the projection of $\mathbf{w}$ onto $\mathbf{y}$.
I already found the orthogonal basis for $W$, with
$$
W = \operatorname{span}\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -4 \\  0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ -7 \\ -4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}, 
$$
as
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -4 \\  0 \\  1 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 9 \\  1 \\ -4 \\-1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}. 
$$
The next part of the question states that for
$$
\mathbf{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -7 \\ -4 \\ -14 \end{bmatrix}, 
$$
I have to find the $\operatorname{proj}_{\mathbf{w}} (\mathbf{y})$. I am confused on how to do this, because I know the projection formula is
$$
\operatorname{proj}_{\mathbf{v}} \mathbf{a} 
= \frac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|^2} \, \mathbf{v}, 
$$
but I am not sure how to apply it since $\mathbf{w}$ has $2$ vectors.

Hint: It suffices to project onto each direction defined by $W.$

You mean the projection of $y$ onto $W$?

If $\mathcal B$ is an orthogonal basis for $W$, show that every vector in $W$ is the sum of its projections onto the vectors in $\mathcal B$.

One way is to see that the projection is the $w$ that solves $\min_{w \in {\cal R}W} |w-x|^2$. Equivalently, it is $Wx$ where $x$ solves $\min_x |Wx-y|^2$ which has a solution $W^TWx = W^T y$. Note that $W^TW$ is the diagonal matrix (because of orthogonality) with diagonal $|w_1|^2,...$. Expand $W (W^T W)^{-1} W^T y$ to get the desired formula.
